# Moving a word forward in z shell

Tags: configuration, keyboard-shortcuts, zsh

In zshell how to move forward word, I can set -o vi and use vi format. Is there a way to move forward in zshell by a word

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The ZLE widget for moving forward by one word is `forward-word`. Therefore, you may use `bindkey` to bind this widget to any key you want.

For example,

```
$> bindkey ^O forward-word
```

would allow you to move forward by one word when pressing `Ctrl-O`. Note that `^O` is actually a quoted insert of Control followed by `O`.

Answer (score 28):

If you're using iTerm2 on OSX, you can use the Natural Text Editing preset under *Preferences -> Profile -> Keys*.

[image: iTerm Keys Preferences]

This supports these key combos (which are very similar to other editors):

- alt/option + left = move left one word
- alt/option + right = move right one word

Comment: Note that you can find this preset only in the *profile* preferences, not in the global preferences.

Comment: This is literally the only thing that worked for me. Thanks Clay!

Comment: I am not getting the option of `Natural Text Editing` presets

Comment: This correctly made option-left move one word left, but option-right rings the terminal bell. Hmmm...

Comment: And it also has broken 'delete', which now tries to do a completion of some sort, unless the command line is empty, in which case it closes the terminal (!). I wonder WTF I did?

Answer (score 19):

Your zsh command prompt works either like emacs or like vi.  If it works like vi, put it in command mode (`esc`) and type `w`.  If it works like emacs, use `M-f`.

More information available at [man zshzle](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/zshzle/).

Comment: For this to work you will need to enable vim mode 'bindkey -v' or if you are using oh-my-zsh install vi-mode plugin

Comment: @Kiril the answer covers both vi-mode `w` and emacs mode `M-f`.

Comment: This solution does not allow you to hold down of `M` and press `f` or `b` repeatedly to move multiple words at a time, which to me is one of the main points of wanting to skip by words.

Answer (score 11):

Similar to other answers, but for Zsh on iTerm it took me a while to find this:

If you are using Zsh, like Oh My Zsh, in iTerm then go to: Preferences > **Profiles** > Keys sub-menu

Click + sign

Add your shortcut combo, choose "Send Escape Sequence"

inputs for left and right below.

left:

```
[1;5D
```

right:

```
[1;5C
```

Comment: Using Zsh in iTerm2, this does not work for me. After doing this, pressing the keys has no visible effect.

Comment: When I define an escape sequence as you say, e.g. "`[1;5D`", the iTerm2 prefs dialog displays it as "`^[ [1;5D`". Should I actually be defining it as "`1;5D`", so that it displays as "`^[ 1;5D`"? Neither works for me though.

Answer (score 6):

- forward word [Meta]+[f]
- backward word [Meta]+[b]

On macOS, [option]+[→] and [option]+[←] work too.

Answer (score 1):

In my zsh terminal it was already set to the below using bindkey

```
"^[f" forward-word 
"^[b" backward-word
```

I was not sure how to use this, read on Apple Forum's, this is basically

`^+[` release it then press `f` or press `esc` release it then press `f`

Similarly for backward,

`^+[` release it then press `b` or press `esc` release it then press `b`

Answer (score 1):

For me, nothing was working until I found out that having `$EDITOR=vim` makes your zsh start in vi mode automatically, which replaces these keybindings. The solution for me was to change my `$EDITOR` variable.

See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197839/why-does-exporting-vim-as-editor-in-zsh-disable-keyboard-shortcuts